# Entity Framework Code first using Fluent Mapping for different Column Key names for different tables and entities

Tags: entity-framework

Using code first with existing database. I have 2 tables with different primary and foreign key name. For example

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID {get; set;}
    public virtual Sale {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Order> Orders {get; set;}
   //props
}

public class Sale
{
    public int saleId {get; set;}
    public int PersID {get; set;}
    //props
}
public class Oder
{
   public int OrderId {get; set;}
   public int pID {get set;}
}
```

Assuming that the PK in table Person is PersonID, in Order is pID and the FK in Sale PersID (so the naming convention for IDs is different from table to table)

How do I map the entities using fluent while taking into consideration the different column ID names?

Answer (score 1):

So EF will already be picking up `PersonID` as the primary key of your Persons (People?) table. Of course, you can always write:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(p => p.PersonID);
```

Then you want to describe the relationship between Person and Sale. I'm going to assume your `Sale` class has a navigation property of type `Person` called "Person":

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().HasRequired(s => s.Person)
                           .WithMany()
                           .HasForeignKey(s => s.PersID);
```

The "HasForeignKey" method lets you specify the property on your class that defines the foreign key value.

Don't forget that it's also ok to omit foreign key properties altogether. You might want to ditch the `PersID` property and tell EF that the database column is called "PersID" like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().HasRequired(s => s.Person)
                           .WithMany()
                           .Map(m => m.MapKey("PersID"));
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Actually there is no navigation property from Sale to person. But just from Person to Sale. How will the mapping then change?

Comment: @Amadou I have no idea how you'd define the relationship if you don't have a navigation property. It's not something I've ever seen done.